# Strong data processing inequality in multiplicative channels

Tags: distributions, information-theory, divergence

We know that postprocessing will not increase the information. For two random variables $X$ and $Y$, $D(X||Y)>= D(f(X)||f(Y))$ for any operation $f()$ and divergence $D$. A strong data processing inequality implies $D(X||Y)> D(f(X)||f(Y))$. This includes operations $f$ such as adding a Gaussian noise. But is there a random multiplicative operation example (especially in multivariate form) such that $D(f^k(X)||f^k(Y))\rightarrow 0$ as $k$ increases. I am wondering whether some simple linear transformation such as iteratively multiplying a random Gaussian matrix satisfies this property.

Comment: could you please format the equations in your question (using LaTex)?

Comment: I think this can depend on the distribution of X and Y: for instance, a condition for what you are looking for to exist (there may be more), is that X and Y are not a dirac in zero, because then any multiplication by something will keep them as such, and you won't be able to have the strict inequality you are looking for.